# Why is the phase velocity of waves on a rope independent of the wave length?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, spring, string, dispersion

A rope is described by the wave equation
$$ (\partial_t^2 - \partial_x^2) \, \varphi = 0 $$
It is well known that there is no dispersion for resulting wave solutions. This implies that all plane waves we can generate in a rope have exactly the same phase velocity. For example, if we focus on one specific point on the rope, say one maximum, it will travel during the time interval $\Delta t$ the distance $\Delta x$. This fact is independent of the wave length of the wave in question. Thus the phase velocity is always $v = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$.

[image]

To analyze the system, let's imagine that a rope consists of lots of mass points that are connected to their neighbors by small strings. For a wave with large wave length the strings between neighboring points are almost not distorted. In contrast, if the wave length is small, the strings between neighboring points are strongly distorted.

Thus, intuitively I would have guessed that the mass points get pulled down much more quickly if the wave length is small. However, as mentioned above, this is not the case as the phase velocity does not depend on the wave length. **How can this be understood in intuitive terms?**

*PS: I recently asked a closely related [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/506188/why-does-the-phase-velocity-of-a-string-attached-to-springs-depend-on-the-wave-l) which sparked this question.*

Comment: Re. "rope consists of lots of mass points that are connected to their neighbors by small strings"  Should this be 'springs' instead of 'strings'?

Comment: @jak Your intuition is right - masses oscillate faster for a low wavelength wave because of greater distortion; it's just that in this case the wave also repeats faster in space...so phase velocity remains the same. If you like, mathematically, low $\lambda$ means low time period $\tau$ of oscillations of a particular point on the string, so that the phase velocity equal to $\lambda/\tau$ stays constant.

Comment: @Vivek thanks a lot! If you copy your comment into an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: "This implies that all plane waves" A plane wave is a wave in 3D space. You may be going for something along the lines of "eigenstate". "For example, if we focus on one specific point on the rope, say one maximum, it will travel during the time interval Δt the distance Δx." The rope only travels in the vertical direction, not the horizontal direction. The phase moves horizontally, but the rope doesn't.

Comment: @Acccumulation Just a matter of semantics in 1D. "Plane" maybe superfluous but isn't wrong obviously.

Comment: @jak I've added a rigorous, intuitive proof at the end now, using insights from relativity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Your intuition is right - masses oscillate faster for a low wavelength wave because of greater distortion; it's just that in this case the wave also repeats faster in space...so phase velocity remains the same. If you like, mathematically, low $\lambda$ means low time period $\tau$ of oscillations of a particular point on the string, so that the phase velocity equal to $\lambda/\tau$ stays constant.

#### Extra Commentary

That the ratio $\omega/k=\lambda/\tau$ is completely independent of $k$ is not easy to answer a priori. What we can say is that high $k$ means more distortion, and hence a more violent normal mode operating at a higher frequency. How high $-$ i.e. proportional to $k^\alpha$ for which value of $\alpha$? That's impossible to claim without the exact formula for the potential energy of distortion. In this case small local length extension is given by $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})^2$, which gives $\alpha = 2/2 = 1$.

Also, for a rope, the aforementioned approximation for the potential energy only works for small amplitudes, and for every amplitude there is a UV cut-off (for $k$) in-built in this system, beyond which the approximation breaks down and/or the rope breaks.

#### Dimensional Analysis

Another heuristic insight is dimensional analysis, which is the next best thing to a field Lagrangian. The only dimensionless combination one can construct in this case is $\omega/ck$, where $c = \sqrt{T/\text{mass density}}$. However, this is assuming the system supports waves and that $T$, mass density are the only relevant physical parameters (case in point: nobody knew vacuum supports EM waves until Maxwell & Hertz found them. Incidentally, this also happens to be an example of dispersionless waves across a very wide range of the EM spectrum as far as we can tell).

Edit

---

#### After-thought: A complete, slick and rigorous proof

I realized this cute argument while answering [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509034/is-there-a-connection-between-spontaneous-symmetry-breaking-and-massless-photons/509076#509076) on stackexchange. The usual wave equation is invariant under Lorentz transformations in which $c$ is equal to the speed of the wave. While this procedure is purely mathematical and doesn't carry a physical interpretation in terms of frames with it in this case, one can still do it and argue that that $(\omega, k)$ transforms like the relativistic four-vector (two vector in 1+1 D) under these transformations, implying $\omega^2-k^2$ is a constant. Using the fact that Goldstone's theorem predicts massless modes, we've $\omega \to 0$ as $k \to 0$, implying that $\omega^2-k^2$ is actually equal to zero (this means we're relying on the existence of "Lorentz transformations" that can produce arbitrary red-shifts, making $k$ as small as we like)!

Comment: Well, this answer is about the wave equation that jak wrote on top of his question. But this is supposing the answer to start with. I am asking a totally different question. Why should this wave equation describe the physical problem of waves travelling along a stressed string ? There is no deep physical reason fo that, one has to do the analysis of the physical situation detail by detail.

Comment: The dimentional analysis is your best attempt. To tell the truth, I buy it. But htat is because I have a long experience of physics. I don't think a layman will be convinced that the only relevants quantities are really T and the linear mass density and so the only quantity with the dimension of a speed is the square root of the ration !

Comment: In fact there is a dimentionless parameter: the ration of the wavelength to the (necessarily finite) radius of the string. Who knows ? The velocity might depend on sqrt(T/linear mass) AND this number. In fact at *very* short wavelength it will be the case. But who can say it does not enter evne at long wavelength, at some power (possibly fractional) ? Dimentional analysis cannot disprove this. Only exact aclculation.

Comment: @Alfred You've to start somewhere to describe your system. So one would either start with the Lagrangian/Hamiltonian or the equation of motion of the string. Assuming that this then goes on to show that the fact that the phase velocity of waves on string is independent of $k$ can be thought to arise intuitively from relativistic insights and Goldstone's theorem. (I remember you saying in a previous post that for a string with springs, the fact that the waves on a string are dispersive is a result of a calculation and so is the fact that without the springs are non-dispersive.)

Comment: Of course, there's a mathematical proof using partial derivatives that such waves are non-dispersive, but that would have been a purely mathematical argument, which neither @jak nor any of us wanted.

Comment: Well, what I keep saying is that the fact the waves are non-dispersive for the physical system of a spring without springs is not intuitive. Your argumeny about relativity insights and Golstone bosons is about a given equation, the one written by jak on top of his question.  Bur how does he know that this equation actually describes the actual case of the string without springs ??? I gave an intuitive argument that allows to obtain the long wavelength limit of the case of tha string **with** strings that shows that in that limit frequency has nonzero limit, so $v=m/k$ : dispersive !

Comment: @Alfred That's actually rather easy to see because the Lagrangian is given by  $L = \int dx \ \frac{1}{2} (\dot(y)^2 -(y')^2)$.

Comment: Why ? What is the physical origin of those two terms ?

Comment: Why ? What is the physical origin of those two terms ? I know it, but is it so "intuitive" for the layman ? Can you give me an intuitive justification for this Lagrangian ? I don't see how to do that. It would need a lot of justifications. Especially the very notion of Lagrangian. Hamiltonian might be more intuitive. But Hamilton equations are not, because the momentum is not so clear.

Comment: And your Lagrangian does not include the finite radius of the string, which will play a role for extremely short wavelengths, comparable to this radius.

Comment: @Alfred This is as obvious as it gets, I think. The first part is kinetic energy and the second is the potential energy of the stretched string. Beyond that I'm not sure what you mean by layman, but I'd assume the target audience is a set of students familiar with the concept of energy & equations of motion.

Comment: @Alfred I'm sorry, but it's understood we're working with a 1D idealisation. A 3D problem would've more degrees of freedom, and a much more complicated description in terms of stress & strains and the associated boundary conditions. And by stretching the problem into that realm (by going to higher $k$) you're saying one will lose intuition - and of course one will. Anybody would agree with that. But your original question wasn't that, was it? As far as I remember, it was why in this 1D case of strings w/o springs there is no dispersion. Feel free to correct me if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Well, indeed, for a 1D case, then dimentional analysis does it. But did you ask jak if he thinks that Goldstone theorem is **intuitive**?  I never discuss the validity of your arguments. Our disagreement is not about physics, but about vocabulary. Your notion of "intuitive" does not match mine. Students familiar wit hte notion of energy and equations of motion can indeed **compute** the equations of motion. I kept agreeing to that. But by pure **intuition** ?

Comment: @Alfred I think intuition is what we develop over time and not what we start with.

Comment: Definitely. However, I was trying to guess what intuition was for jak. I have forty years of professional physics, and (except if one considers dimensional analysis, but this is already computations) I ahve not yet developed an intuition about why velocity of waves on an string is constant. Though I do have an intuition that with the springs, the frequency is starts with $m$ at $k=0$ and increases with $k$ but for $k$ small enough, the velocity is  almost $m/k$ and thus dispersive, and this, whether is goes to a constant value for large $k$ or not.

Comment: @Alfred Well, I agree this is a retrospective insight and I'm not offering anything new. It's quite unlikely one would think like this about this problem when one confronts it. However, since now we've insights from relativity & Einstein, we can borrow that argument and say why we necessarily get the result we do. And the answer is exactly in the same way electromagnetic waves have the same phase velocity! Otherwise we could catch up with one of them, resulting in a contradiction!

Comment: Sorry, but though I buy the Goldstone argument (highly non intuitive, but correct) the one I absolutely not understand is the relativity one. I can certainly catch up with a sound wave on a string ! The fact that the string is material precludes the "Lorentz invariance" of transformations on a string. What does it have to do with electromagnetic waves ? Once again my point is not what you do of hte wave equation once you've got it but HOW DO YOU GET IT from the physical situation. I keep claiming it is not "intuitive" And even Goldstone does not prevent  $\omega^2=m^2+k^4$

Comment: I mean, of course "Goldstone in the limit $m=0$", since the presence of the springs destroys the translational invariance hence the $m^2$ term. But without springs, why not $k^4$ instead of $k^2$ ? Who says the equation is second order ? Intuition ?